# Truffle test, how to get address(0)?

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

This is going to be short question and may be silly, but I'm literally stuck with a problem, where I need to pass `address(0)` to function in Truffle Test in JS and don't really know how to do it. In solidity it's simply `address(0)`, but in Truffle JS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `0`, or `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

`address(0)` in Solidity is equivalent to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: I get invalid address error, with Truffle 5, Web3 1, Solidity .5

Comment: To be clear, you have to use it as a String:

`zero_address = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";`

this works for me.

Answer (score 6):

You must put single quotes around it.
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' worked for me
Been hunting down that bug for some time ...

Comment: this did not work for me :|

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about web3.js, but in ethers.js `ethers.constants.AddressZero` will do the work.

Example:
Suppose you have a transfer function in your contract like this:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    require(to != address(0), "Transfer to the zero address");
    ////
    ////
}
```

you can test this by:

```
await expect(
  contract.transfer(ethers.constants.AddressZero, amount)
).to.be.revertedWith("Transfer to the zero address");
```

You can check out this link for reference: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/constants/#constants-AddressZero

Comment: Hello. Providing a little sample and a link to the function documentation would make this answer way better ;)

Comment: As of ethers v6 it is simply `ethers.ZeroAddress`